# Magento 2 configurable product not open

Tags: magento-2.1

I migrate one of my client's website from Magento 1.7 to Magento 2.1.
All products work properly but when I open configurable product from admin it will not open and give this kind of message.
[image]

And also in system log "[2016-09-15 07:43:56] main.CRITICAL: Requested product doesn't exist [] []" this message appear.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify these things.

1. Run this command from your magento.

   php bin/magento cache:clean

   php bin/magento cache:flush

   php bin/magento indexer:reindex

2.Verify product is avilabel in database.

3.Try to load product by id using any magento script.